# Cannot import skimage.transform

Tags: python, import

When I use `import` command:

```
import skimage.transform
```

I obtain the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14996\4121784789.py in <module>
      9 from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input
     10 from keras.datasets.mnist import load_data
---> 11 from skimage.transform import resize

~\anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\skimage\transform\__init__.py in <module>
      2                               probabilistic_hough_line, hough_circle,
      3                               hough_circle_peaks, hough_ellipse)
----> 4 from .radon_transform import (radon, iradon, iradon_sart,
      5                               order_angles_golden_ratio)
      6 from .finite_radon_transform import frt2, ifrt2

~\anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\skimage\transform\radon_transform.py in <module>
      3 from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
      4 from scipy.constants import golden_ratio
----> 5 from ._warps import warp
      6 from ._radon_transform import sart_projection_update
      7 from .._shared.fft import fftmodule

~\anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\skimage\transform\_warps.py in <module>
      5                          ProjectiveTransform, _to_ndimage_mode)
      6 from ._warps_cy import _warp_fast
----> 7 from ..measure import block_reduce
      8 
      9 from .._shared.utils import (get_bound_method_class, safe_as_int, warn,

~\anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from ._find_contours import find_contours
      2 from ._marching_cubes_lewiner import marching_cubes_lewiner, marching_cubes
      3 from ._marching_cubes_classic import (marching_cubes_classic,
      4                                       mesh_surface_area)
      5 from ._regionprops import (regionprops, perimeter,

~\anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure\_find_contours.py in <module>
      9 
     10 
---> 11 @deprecate_kwarg({'array': 'image'}, removed_version="0.20")
     12 def find_contours(image, level=None,
     13                   fully_connected='low', positive_orientation='low',

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'deprecated_version'
```

I tried to reinstall `skicit-image` but it gave me nothing. Do you know why this problem occurs?

Comment: Please show the full traceback. That might at least give us a hint.

Comment: There you go ;))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but have you pip installed it, also, you can try from skimage import * which imports all 'sub-modules' of skimage, to be on the safe side

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).